# Wortfolge in diesen "Fragen"

Tags: wortfolge

*1*
a) Hast du das Hexerzeichen?
b) Du hast das Hexerzeichen?
c) Das Hexerzeichen hast du?

*2*
a) Hast du einen Namen?
b) Du hast einen Namen?
c) Einen Namen hast du?

Wie verhält es sich mit Varianten 2 und 3? Wäre eine von ihnen in dem unten dargestellten Fragment angebracht?

> ***"Das Hexerzeichen hast du?"***

> *Der Unbekannte griff abermals in den Ausschnitt des Kaftans, woraufhin er ein rundes Medalion an einer silbernen Kette ausgrub. Es zeigte den Kopf eines Wolfes mit gefletschten Fängen.*

> ***"Einen Namen hast du?*** *Irgendeinen. Ich frage nicht aus Neugier, sondern um das Gespräch zu erleichtern."*

> *Ich kümmere mich hier in Wyzima um Recht und Ordnung und lasse nicht zu,  dass Leute getötet werden! Verstanden?"*

> *Rive nickte, um zu bestätigen, dass er verstanden hat.
> Valerad keuchte ärgerlich.*

Dass ich Variante 1 hier nicht verwenden will, folgt daraus, dass wir in dem unteren Fragment eigentlich mit keiner Frage zu tun haben. Nehmen wir so eine Situation: Wir sehen, dass jemand mit einem Fahrrad angekommen ist und wir "fragen" diese Person: "Du bist heute mit dem Fahrrad da?", NICHT: "Bist du heute mit dem Fahrrad da?". Oder jemand trinkt in unserer Gegenwart Kaffee: Es wäre dumm, ihn zu fragen: "Trinkst du Kaffee um diese Zeit?" Man sollte fragen ("fragen" in Anführungszeichen, da das mit einer Frage nur soviel zu tun hat, dass es ein Fragezeichen enthält, sonst keine Gemeinsamkeiten, das ist nur Ausdruck der Überraschung und nicht eine Suche nach Information): "Du trinkst Kaffee um diese Uhrzeit?".

Und im dargestellten Fragment stellt der Kastellan dem Hexer eigentlich keine Frage... Eigentlich weiß er, dass er sowohl das Hexenzeichen als auch einen Namen hat. Er fragt nur formalitätshalber. Na ja, theoretisch kann er nicht wissen, ob sein Gegenüber Hexer ist, aber manchmal sieht man jemandem etwas so deutlich an... Manchmal strahlt eine Eigenschaft von einer Person stark aus, oder der situative Kontext löst bei uns eine starke, mit Gewissheit grenzende Annahme aus, dass man sagen kann, dass man etwas weiß, obwohl man das, streng genommen, nicht wissen kann.

Jetzt ist mir noch ein ähnliches Beispiel in den Sinn gekommen: Wie würdet ihr schreiben, wenn ein uniformierter Polizist einem Fragen zu einem Vorfall stellen will, worauf dieser ihn nach seinem Polizeiabzeichen fragt: "Haben sie das Abzeichen?" würde unnatürlich klingen, stimmt's? Die richtige Wortfolge wäre: "Sie haben das Abzeichen?". Diese Frage wäre in diesem Fall de facto keine Frage, denn man würde sie nicht stellen, um die Antwort ja/nein oder sonst eine zu bekommen (anders wäre es natürlich, wenn man mit einer nicht uniformierten Person zu tun hätte). Diese "Frage" hieße de facto "Zeigen Sie mir bitte ihr Abzeichen".

Und zurück zur eigentlichen Frage: 2 und 3 würden in dem zitierten Fragment funktionieren?

EDITIERUNG nach der Antwort:

Danke für die gute Antwort. Ich habe jetzt nach deinen Tipps die Aufnahmen gemacht:

Variante 3:

Das Hexerzeichen hast du?
Einen Namen hast du?
https://voca.ro/1eAawr3OFoQX

Variante 2:

Du hast das Hexerzeichen?
Du hast einen Namen?
https://voca.ro/1omjfEVbhli3

Comment: In beiden Aufnahmen passt die Betonung nicht. Betone stattdessen die mit ' markierten Silben: *Das 'Hexerzeichen 'hast du? Einen 'Namen 'hast du?* und *Du 'hast das 'Hexerzeichen? Du 'hast einen 'Namen?* Und denke daran, dass in Fragen die letzte Silbe einen steigenden Ton hat statt wie üblich einen fallenden.

Comment: Wenn du keine Antwort suggerieren willst, musst du auf jeden Fall *'Hast du das 'Hexerzeichen?* verwenden. Für den Namen ist es von der Logik her nicht möglich, keine Antwort zu suggerieren, da ja jeder einen Namen hat.

Comment: Wenn du die Antwort *ja* suggerieren willst, kannst du beide anderen Varianten verwenden. Beim Namen wieder mit der Einschränkung, dass allgemein bekannt ist, dass jeder einen Namen hat. Ich würde auf jeden Fall das Objekt zum Thema machen. Die andere Variante klingt sehr langweilig.

Answer (score 3):

Diese drei Sätze unterscheiden sich nur im gesetzten Thema.

> Hast du das Hexerzeichen? Hast du es, ja oder nein?

Verberststellung, kein Imperativ: Ja/Nein-Frage ohne Thema.

> Du hast das Hexerzeichen? Wirklich? Du?

Verbzweitstellung, Aussagesatz, Fragezeichen: Ja/Nein-Frage mit Thema *du*.

> Das Hexerzeichen hast du? Ich setze das mal voraus.

Verbzweitstellung, Aussagesatz, Fragezeichen: Ja/Nein-Frage mit Thema *das Hexerzeichen*.

Alle drei Varianten sind möglich. Es kommt darauf an was du als Thema, also aus dem Vorwissen bekannt, markieren willst. Und genauso mit dem anderen Beispiel, wobei hier aber noch hinzukommt, dass aus dem Vorwissen bekannt ist, dass jeder einen Namen hat. Die Frage ist also in jedem Fall als rhetorische Frage gemeint und eigentlich eine Aussage.

> Hast du einen Namen? Wir wurden einander noch nicht vorgestellt, schönes Kind.

> Du hast einen Namen? Ich dachte eigentlich, alle nennen dich ‘He, du da.‘

> Einen Namen hast du? Warum hast du mir den nicht schon längst gesagt, du Depp?